# How do I load the latest code in Cake REPL?

Tags: cakephp, read-eval-print-loop

When I make changes to my Entity code, the changes only reflect after restarting the REPL console. How do I always have the latest code in my REPL console?

```php
./bin/cake console
> $ac_table = Cake\Datasource\FactoryLocator::get('Table')->get('AccountChannels');
> $ac = $ac_table->find()->first()
> $ac->someFunc(); // I can only see changes to this function after restarting the console
```

I also tried to reload the entity with the `first()` call after a code change, but no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CakePHP uses [**PsySH**](https://github.com/bobthecow/psysh) under the hood, and currently it doesn't support code reloading, unless you can get a [**runkit**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.runkit7.php) version with import support running in your PHP environment.

> Hey there's an existing [fork](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.runkit7.php) of runkit for php7. Unfortunatly the `runkit_import` function was removed in version [4.0.0a1](https://pecl.php.net/package-info.php?package=runkit7&version=4.0.0a1), apparently because of bugs with `php7.3+`, so this will not work for latest versions of php, but it should be mostly ok for earlier versions (haven't fully tested though). To install:
>
> 1. `pecl install runkit7-3.1.0a1`
> 2. I created a [PR](https://github.com/bobthecow/psysh/pull/667) to update `RunkitReloader.php` class
>    (nb: might not work for class props, see pr modifications)

**https://github.com/bobthecow/psysh/issues/416#issuecomment-776631583**

**https://github.com/bobthecow/psysh/issues/416**